# Using itertools to create all combinations up to a value

Tags: python, list, lambda, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have this code:

```
return [reduce(lambda x,y: str(x)+str(y), perm) 
        for perm in itertools.combinations(alphabet, n)]
```

My problem is I want it to be for all values up to n.  It's for homework and I'm having trouble making this a single line Pythonic statement.  How would I continue in this manner so I could add a statement like:

```
 return [reduce(lambda x,y: str(x)+str(y), perm) 
         for perm in itertools.combinations(alphabet, n) for n in range(1,n+1)]
```

except one that actually works?

Comment: permutations or combinations? Itertools offers both, I believe

Comment: just working on combinations for this one

Comment: Posting your homework on stackoverflow? Is your teacher ok with that?

Comment: fix the title of your question then

Comment: Also, can you please clarify what you mean by all values upto n? what is `n`? If its a variable, what does its value have? Also what is the output you are expecting from this?

Comment: It's precoursework so I don't really have anyone to get help from, if you think this is unethical I respect your point of view but respectfully disagree.  I don't have anyone in my area to compare notes with and it's hard to teach yourself everything.

Comment: in example, combinations of '1234' for n = 2 would be:

['1','2','3','4','12', '13', '14', '23', '24','34']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> from itertools import combinations, chain
>>> limit = 10
>>> c = chain(*(combinations(alphabet, x) for x in range(1, limit+1)))
>>> list(c)
```

I won't display the output, it's too long.

Edit: based on your comments above, it seems like you want the output in the form of strings, so

```
[''.join(s) for s in chain(*(combinations(alphabet, x) for x in range(1, limit+1)))]
```

Comment: ya that definitely helps, I've been struggling with formatting it so much, I'll have to research chain more but this will get me moving in the right direction.

Comment: @Rob I made an edit to show you how to use a list comprehension to turn the tuples outputted by `combinations` into strings using `str.join`.

Comment: `itertools.chain` just joins together multiple iterables. `(combinations(alphabet, x) for x in range(1, limit+1))` gives you a set of combination generators: one iterable for all the combinations of length 1, another iterable for the combinations of length 2, etc. Then `chain` joins them into one long list.

Comment: this was my final answer in case anyone else is curious:

return [reduce(lambda x,y: str(x)+str(y), perm) for perm in (itertools.chain(*(itertools.combinations(alphabet, x) for x in range(1, n+1))))]

Comment: @Rob are you using `reduce` just to join together the values as strings? See the edit to my post for a simpler way.

Comment: ok cool, i need to start using chain more because having a list of lists of tuples and trying to figure out how to unpack it is driving me insane.

Comment: @Rob list comprehensions are awesome. Also note the use of the `*` operator to unpack the comrehension containing the combinations so that `chain` sees it as multiple arguments.